# Create a schedule where a group of people all talk to each other - with restrictions

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

### Problem statement

I would like to achieve the following:
(could be used for example to organize some sort of a speeddating event for students)

Create a schedule so people talk to each other one-on-one and this to each member of the group.
but with restrictions.

- **Input**: list of people. (eg. 30 people)
- **Restrictions**: some of the people should not talk to each other (eg. they know each other)
- **Output**: List of pairs (separated into sessions) just one solution is ok, no need to know all of the possible outcomes

### Example

eg. Group of 4 people

1. John
2. Steve
3. Mark
4. Melissa

Restrictions: John - Mellisa -> NO

Outcome

Session one

- John - Steve
- Mark - Melissa

Session two

- John - Mark
- Steve - Melissa

Session three

- Steve - Mark

John and Mellisa will not join session three as it is restriction.

### Question

Is there a way to approach this using Python or even excel?

I am especially looking for some pointers how this problem is called as I assume this is some Should I look towards some solver? Dynamic programming etc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428614/groups-of-unique-pairs-where-members-appear-once-per-group

Comment: Thats already very interesting. How would one add restrictions to it. Eg teams from the same country should not play against each other. I indeed just need a solution, not a perfect solution.

Comment: You could have a check for each pair that the algorithm might make, and not generate a pair if there shouldn’t be one.

Comment: Apparently there need to be sessions until everyone has been paired up with every possible partner once? Does the solution need to be optimal? (i.e. the least number of sessions with the least number of waiting people until the very end for everyone to meet every possible candidate?)

Comment: Very helpful remark. I would like to limit the amount of sessions so I will have some people which will not talk to each other but thats fine, The cutoff would be rather random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly naive implementation:

```
from itertools import combinations
from typing import Set, List, Generator


def generate_sessions(people: Set, excl: List[Set]) -> Generator[List[Set], None, None]:
    # all the pairings you need are all possible pairings, except the exclusions
    needed_pairings = [set(pair) for pair in combinations(people, 2)]
    for pair in excl:
        needed_pairings.remove(pair)

    # while there pairing that haven't happened yet
    while needed_pairings:
        # each session starts empty
        session = []
        # keep track of all people still available for this session
        available = set(people)
        # create an iterator, so we can loop over the needed pairings
        iter_needed_pairings = iter(needed_pairings)
        # as long as there are more than 2 people still waiting and there's a pair left in the needed pairings
        while (len(available) > 1) and (pair := next(iter_needed_pairings, False)):
            # are both people in the pair in the group of available people?
            if available.intersection(pair) == pair:
                # then they can meet in this session
                session.append(pair)
                # and they're no longer available
                available -= pair
        # once we have a session, remove the pairs in it from the pairings still needed
        for pair in session:
            needed_pairings.remove(pair)
        # yield the session
        yield session


print(list(generate_sessions(people={'John', 'Steve', 'Mark', 'Melissa'}, excl=[{'John', 'Melissa'}])))
```

Result (can vary, due to unordered nature of sets):

```
[[{'John', 'Mark'}, {'Melissa', 'Steve'}], [{'John', 'Steve'}, {'Melissa', 'Mark'}], [{'Mark', 'Steve'}]]
```

This generates sessions until everyone has met. You could just get the `next()` from the generator until you have enough sessions. The only downside to this approach is that it may find a sessions where a few people are waiting before a session that has more people meeting. You could solve that by sorting the sessions by length, but of course that means generating all of them.

Edit: I added typing info, to make it clear what the expected types are, but of course it doesn't need that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your given information is pretty generous, you have a set of all the students, and a set of no-go pairs (because you said it yourself, and it makes it easy to explain, just say this is a set of pairs of students who know each other). So we can iterate through our students list creating random pairings so long as they do not exist in our no-go set, then expand our no-go set with them, and recurse on the remaining students until we can not create any pairs that do not exist already in the no-go set (we have pairings so that every student has met all students).

Comment: Your approach doesn't deal with the case where two pairings are added to a session that include the same person. For example, John should not meet both Mark and Steve in the same session.