# Schedule optimization problem - distribute N amount of users over N 2 rooms as pairs

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a scheduling problem to solve and not really sure how further solve it.
We have 26 participants which we have to spread over 13 virtual rooms for 1 on 1
meetings. This only for 10 sessions.

I should be able to set limitations like person A should not talk to person B.
But if not possible, This can be relaxed.

So the goal is to have a schedule like this:

- **Input** = 26 email addresses
- **Limitation** = a cannot talk to b / C cannot talk to D
- **Output** = 10 x 13 sessions van 1 on ones.

**Sessie 1**

- room 1 -> John - Mark
- other rooms
- room 13 -> David - Bart

**Sessie 2**

- room 1 John -> Bart
- other rooms
- room 13  David - Mark

This for 10 sessions in total.

What is the best way to approach this?
I mainly need some help how to approach this.

Related question was this one

- [Create a schedule where a group of people all talk to each other - with restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163061/create-a-schedule-where-a-group-of-people-all-talk-to-each-other-with-restrict/65163460#65163460)

Comment: Your question is "how can this be solved in general" or "what is THE BEST way to solve this"? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: No just a solution would be good if a certain limit needs to be relaxed thats ok. Just not sure what to use for this? Is this a constraint solving problem? Should i use tools like optaplanner for this? Or can you do this simply in python for example?

Comment: It can be solved with a couple of proper dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an algorithm to make this kind of schedule here: https://nrich.maths.org/1443

Here's an example of the algorithm in Python (works for even and odd number of people):

```
def roundRobin(people):
    count     = len(people)
    even      = 1-(count&1)
    poly      = people[even:]
    for _ in range(count-even):
        rooms  = [(people[0],poly[0])]*even
        rooms += [(poly[i],poly[count-i-even]) for i in range(1,(count+1)//2)]
        yield rooms
        poly = poly[1:]+poly[:1]
```

Even number of people (6)

```
for session,meetings in enumerate(roundRobin(["A","B","C","D","E","F"]),1):
    print(session,meetings)
# 1 [('A', 'B'), ('C', 'F'), ('D', 'E')]
# 2 [('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('E', 'F')]
# 3 [('A', 'D'), ('E', 'C'), ('F', 'B')]
# 4 [('A', 'E'), ('F', 'D'), ('B', 'C')]
# 5 [('A', 'F'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D')]
```

Odd number of people (7)

```
for session,meetings in enumerate(roundRobin(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]),1):
    print(session,meetings)
# 1 [('B', 'G'), ('C', 'F'), ('D', 'E')] ("A" sits out)
# 2 [('C', 'A'), ('D', 'G'), ('E', 'F')] ("B" sits out)
# 3 [('D', 'B'), ('E', 'A'), ('F', 'G')] ("C" sits out)
# 4 [('E', 'C'), ('F', 'B'), ('G', 'A')] ("D" sits out)
# 5 [('F', 'D'), ('G', 'C'), ('A', 'B')] ("E" sits out)
# 6 [('G', 'E'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C')] ("F" sits out)
# 7 [('A', 'F'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D')] ("G" sits out)
```

26 people

```
for session,meetings in enumerate(roundRobin(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")),1):
    print(session,", ".join(f"{a}-{b}" for a,b in meetings))
# 1 A-B, C-Z, D-Y, E-X, F-W, G-V, H-U, I-T, J-S, K-R, L-Q, M-P, N-O
# 2 A-C, D-B, E-Z, F-Y, G-X, H-W, I-V, J-U, K-T, L-S, M-R, N-Q, O-P
# 3 A-D, E-C, F-B, G-Z, H-Y, I-X, J-W, K-V, L-U, M-T, N-S, O-R, P-Q
# 4 A-E, F-D, G-C, H-B, I-Z, J-Y, K-X, L-W, M-V, N-U, O-T, P-S, Q-R
# 5 A-F, G-E, H-D, I-C, J-B, K-Z, L-Y, M-X, N-W, O-V, P-U, Q-T, R-S
# 6 A-G, H-F, I-E, J-D, K-C, L-B, M-Z, N-Y, O-X, P-W, Q-V, R-U, S-T
# 7 A-H, I-G, J-F, K-E, L-D, M-C, N-B, O-Z, P-Y, Q-X, R-W, S-V, T-U
# 8 A-I, J-H, K-G, L-F, M-E, N-D, O-C, P-B, Q-Z, R-Y, S-X, T-W, U-V
# 9 A-J, K-I, L-H, M-G, N-F, O-E, P-D, Q-C, R-B, S-Z, T-Y, U-X, V-W
# 10 A-K, L-J, M-I, N-H, O-G, P-F, Q-E, R-D, S-C, T-B, U-Z, V-Y, W-X
# 11 A-L, M-K, N-J, O-I, P-H, Q-G, R-F, S-E, T-D, U-C, V-B, W-Z, X-Y
# 12 A-M, N-L, O-K, P-J, Q-I, R-H, S-G, T-F, U-E, V-D, W-C, X-B, Y-Z
# 13 A-N, O-M, P-L, Q-K, R-J, S-I, T-H, U-G, V-F, W-E, X-D, Y-C, Z-B
# 14 A-O, P-N, Q-M, R-L, S-K, T-J, U-I, V-H, W-G, X-F, Y-E, Z-D, B-C
# 15 A-P, Q-O, R-N, S-M, T-L, U-K, V-J, W-I, X-H, Y-G, Z-F, B-E, C-D
# 16 A-Q, R-P, S-O, T-N, U-M, V-L, W-K, X-J, Y-I, Z-H, B-G, C-F, D-E
# 17 A-R, S-Q, T-P, U-O, V-N, W-M, X-L, Y-K, Z-J, B-I, C-H, D-G, E-F
# 18 A-S, T-R, U-Q, V-P, W-O, X-N, Y-M, Z-L, B-K, C-J, D-I, E-H, F-G
# 19 A-T, U-S, V-R, W-Q, X-P, Y-O, Z-N, B-M, C-L, D-K, E-J, F-I, G-H
# 20 A-U, V-T, W-S, X-R, Y-Q, Z-P, B-O, C-N, D-M, E-L, F-K, G-J, H-I
# 21 A-V, W-U, X-T, Y-S, Z-R, B-Q, C-P, D-O, E-N, F-M, G-L, H-K, I-J
# 22 A-W, X-V, Y-U, Z-T, B-S, C-R, D-Q, E-P, F-O, G-N, H-M, I-L, J-K
# 23 A-X, Y-W, Z-V, B-U, C-T, D-S, E-R, F-Q, G-P, H-O, I-N, J-M, K-L
# 24 A-Y, Z-X, B-W, C-V, D-U, E-T, F-S, G-R, H-Q, I-P, J-O, K-N, L-M
# 25 A-Z, B-Y, C-X, D-W, E-V, F-U, G-T, H-S, I-R, J-Q, K-P, L-O, M-N
```

If you have only 10 sessions, you can afford to filter out some of the output from that function and only take the number of sessions that you need:

```
schedule = [ r for r in roundRobin(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
             if  not {"A","B"} in map(set,r)
             and not {"C","D"} in map(set,r)]

for session,meetings in enumerate(schedule[:10],1):
    print(session,", ".join(f"{a}-{b}" for a,b in meetings))

# 1 A-C, D-B, E-Z, F-Y, G-X, H-W, I-V, J-U, K-T, L-S, M-R, N-Q, O-P
# 2 A-D, E-C, F-B, G-Z, H-Y, I-X, J-W, K-V, L-U, M-T, N-S, O-R, P-Q
# 3 A-E, F-D, G-C, H-B, I-Z, J-Y, K-X, L-W, M-V, N-U, O-T, P-S, Q-R
# 4 A-F, G-E, H-D, I-C, J-B, K-Z, L-Y, M-X, N-W, O-V, P-U, Q-T, R-S
# 5 A-G, H-F, I-E, J-D, K-C, L-B, M-Z, N-Y, O-X, P-W, Q-V, R-U, S-T
# 6 A-H, I-G, J-F, K-E, L-D, M-C, N-B, O-Z, P-Y, Q-X, R-W, S-V, T-U
# 7 A-I, J-H, K-G, L-F, M-E, N-D, O-C, P-B, Q-Z, R-Y, S-X, T-W, U-V
# 8 A-J, K-I, L-H, M-G, N-F, O-E, P-D, Q-C, R-B, S-Z, T-Y, U-X, V-W
# 9 A-K, L-J, M-I, N-H, O-G, P-F, Q-E, R-D, S-C, T-B, U-Z, V-Y, W-X
# 10 A-L, M-K, N-J, O-I, P-H, Q-G, R-F, S-E, T-D, U-C, V-B, W-Z, X-Y
```